# Online view of what the Scala.js compiler generates

Tags: scala.js

Is there a page somewhere that allows me to write short snippets in Scala and to check the corresponding (possibly optimised) JavaScript spit out by the Scala.js compiler?

Would be great for short demos to friends and colleagues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/) supports this feature, although it's hidden. Write your code on the left, then hit Ctrl+J. The optimized generated code appears on the right. Note that it's the code for the *entire* app, so there's a lot there. Usually a good starting point is to Ctrl+F for `function $c_LScalaFiddle$()`.

Comment: Thanks! Any way I can disable the (of some of?) the optimisation steps? It looks like it can be challenging to map the results to the Scala source. Maybe access to the source map would help?

Comment: I don't think ScalaFiddle gives you any of that. You could request a feature. Source maps won't help you unless you have a very good tool to *visualize* them (if you do, I'm all ears!).

Comment: Couldn't one use source maps to highlight corresponding lines in the generated JavaScript? This comes to mind: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map#sourcemapconsumerprototypeallgeneratedpositionsfororiginalposition